# Overwhelmed about managing 2 LAN

Tags: networking, server, 16.04

I am probably going to lose reputation with this question but I have been running around for hours and I am just completely lost.

This is a scenario where I am trying to connect a bunch of IP cameras on a separate switch and subnet. To isolate camera's traffic from the main LAN.

I have my network of switches and everything is on the same subnet (192.168.1.X - 255.255.255.0)
I also have a 24 ports POE switch which will be dedicated to all my cameras. I was planing to set the cameras on a different subnet (192.168.2.X - 255.255.255.0)
On the server that will control the cameras (Ubuntu server 16.04 x64) there is 2 NIC. I would Connect 1 card of my cam server to 192.168.1.X subnet(to the main LAN) and the other card to 192.168.2.X(to the POE switch)

So, on the cam server I am able to monitor all the cameras on 192.168.2.x and I am able to manage the cam server on 192.168.1.X. (Works great)

All that I need to understand now is how to be able to manage each camera on 192.168.2.X from 192.168.1.X bypassing the Camera software on the Camera server.

I was not able to figure out how to set the Ubuntu 16.04 server to grab some traffic coming from 192.168.1.x and pass it to 192.168.2.x ???

Is there some packages already included in Ubuntu 16.04 to help me with that? This could help me as a starting point.

Is my question going to remain with [On Hold] status?
It asked me to edit my question and I did.
I really think this is a Ubuntu related question if I compare it to many other accepted questions.

Comment: So what's the point of the server on both subnets i thought it was suppose to manage all cameras? Now you want to manage them from any computer on 192.168.1.X? And what does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: @meccooll is there some packages already included in Ubuntu to help me with that? This could help me as a starting point. The reason I 'd like to be able to connect directly to the cameras is that the server is kind of limited and some features are only available on the camera's own web management page.

Comment: @TiriPon Well, `dnsmasq` is included in Ubuntu, and is very easy to configure, and would help with the problem.

Comment: Even if you don't have enough reputation to *embed* pictures in your post you can still *link* to them.

Comment: @dobey Thanks. It is not easy to me but now that I know where to look I can spend more time trying to figure this one out with confidence I am going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is handing out DHCP to the devices on the networks?

It's really quite simple. You simply need to hand out in the DHCP a route for the 192.168.2.XXX network to the devices in the 192.168.1.XXX network, which tells them to route through the IP of your server (192.168.1.1 if that's it). Then it should just work for the devices in the 192.168.1.XXX network to talk to the cameras in the 192.168.2.XXX network. You may also need to send the reverse routing to the 192.168.2.XXX network so they can route to 192.168.1.XXX via your server.

Comment: It sounds simple indeed. I did not know I could distribute routes through DHCP. The thing is I have no idea how to do all that and I did not enabled DHCP. I manually assign IPs to the cameras. It's going to be only about 20 cameras.

Comment: Without DHCP, you'll have to manually add the necessary routing on every device you want to talk across the network boundary.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate it if someone could direct me to step-by-step instructions on how to do "routes" using dnsmasq? This is way to hard for me. The only things I managed to do is install it and enable DHCP on the second interface. The rest becomes very complicated for me.

Comment: The configuration file is self-documenting. Search for `dhcp-options=3` in the file. That is the bit for sending the gateway IP. There is a large comment above that option, explaining the `dhcp-option` config value and how to send different options with DHCP.

Comment: Thank you so much to take the time to consult me. Sadly, I am still far from getting this to work. Right now, I am stuck where IPs are simply not being distributed. I did not do much. I "sudo apt-get dnsmasq" and "sudo nano /etc/dnsmasq.conf" There I set the dhcp-range and set the interface to my second card. Added dhcp-option=3 and 6 for gateway and dns and that is all. But even after rebooting no ips get distributed. I am testing with a laptop and I can ping the server if I enter manually the ip address. dnsmasq -status = "dnsmasq: failed to bind DHCP server socket: Address already in use"